# How to find a vector perpendicular to plane ABC given A,B and C

Tags: vectors

> Let $A=(1,0,1)$, $B=(2,1,-1)$, $C(0,1,2)$

Find a vector perpendicular to the plane $ABC$.

the solution I was given by my lecturer:

[image]

Does it matter which vectors I use?

Because my attempt has got the exact opposite sign.

[image]

Comment: Hint: cross product of two vectors

Comment: @MattiP. I have the solution and it shows that: they use AB x AC but how do you know to use these two vectors?

Comment: You have to find a vector perpendicular to any two vectors in the plane. You can use AB and AC ,or AB and BC, or AC and BC

Comment: I want to emphasize that it could have been literally *any* two vectors so long as they were nonzero, linearly independent, and were both in the plane.  There are infinitely many such choices.  That they used $AB\times AC$ was merely personal preference on their part as they are some of the most apparent examples of vectors from the plane.

Comment: @Tojrah thanks for your help! I have updated the question to be a bit more specific and show my solution which seems to be a bit off

Comment: @JMoravitz (see above)

Comment: Again, sign does not matter, the two vectors opposite to each other, along same line are perpendicular to a plane.

Comment: You may also use the zero vector.

Comment: Sorry, I probably being really slow but why does the sign not matter

Comment: @MichaelHoppe how can I apply zero vector?

Comment: Consider a simple example, the plane $x=1.$ You have vectors perpendicular to the plane in both directions, toward positive $x$ and toward negative $x.$ Examples are $\mathbf i$ and $-\mathbf i.$

Comment: There's no single distinguished perpendicular vector, there's a whole 1-dimensional space of perpendicular vectors. If you find one such non-zero vector, you can obtain all the others by multiplying by various real numbers. Including -1. That's why the sign doesn't matter. Speaking of which, neither does the length, as long as it is non-zero.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations that makes sense now

Comment: @jdog Because the zero vector trivially is perpendicular to any other vector.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is basically alright.

Take combination ABC and compute a unit normal vector P . Next take combination DBC and compute a unit normal vector Q.

In general, cross product M X N has sign opposite to that of N X M. The product vectors have opposite *sense*.

If P,Q are same then the sense is same, else the opposite sense has prevailed.

(If the vectors are altogether different then the four sides are not in the same plane.)

Comment: I'm not sure if I've fully understood your answer. Am I right in saying that the sign is basically given by the direction of the unit vector n in the equation: a×b = |a||b|sin(θ)n

Comment: The sign is given by the Right Hand Rule. The cross vector  product of Thumb and Index fingers ..in that order..gives middle finger vector direction.of product .. When thumb/index fingers are swapped the sense changes to the opposite.